# Box size variation during rotation of 3d data

Tags: graphics3d

I have s set 3d data points which I want to rotate, so that the size of the box does not change. Also if possible the window size which contains the plot should not change ist size.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[10, {500, 3}];

Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    {PointSize[Medium], Point[data, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[data[[All, 1]]])]}, 
    SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True, 
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
    ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis", "z axis"}, 
    ViewPoint -> 
      N @ Dynamic[15*{Sin[α] Cos[β], Sin[α] Sin[β], Cos[α]}], ImageSize -> Small], 
  {{α, N @ π/3}, N @ π/360, π, π/360, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{β, N@π/4}, 0., 2 π, 2 π/360, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Use clear values `ImageSize -> {600, 400}` instead of `Small`.

Comment: And explicit `ImagePadding`, like `ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}`.

Comment: Also `SphericalRegion -> True` helps to avoid the view point depending shifting of the box.

Comment: @Thies `SphericalRegion` was also my first reaction, but then realized that it was already included among the options.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I see, cool! Didn't notice that. It might still be useful to be aware the parameter exists as a reference for future visitors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ContentSize` and `Aligment`, along with `SphericalRegion`:

```
Manipulate[
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], 
Point[data, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[data[[All, 1]]])]}, 
SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True, 
AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
ViewProjection -> "Ortographic", Boxed -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis", "z axis"}, 
ViewPoint -> 
N@Dynamic[
 50*{Sin[\[Alpha]] Cos[\[Beta]], Sin[\[Alpha]] Sin[\[Beta]], 
   Cos[\[Alpha]]}]
],
{{\[Alpha], N@\[Pi]/3}, N@\[Pi]/360, \[Pi], \[Pi]/360, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Beta], N@\[Pi]/4}, 0., 2 \[Pi], 
2 \[Pi]/360, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
Alignment -> Center,
ContentSize -> {400, 400},
Initialization :> (SeedRandom[1]; data = RandomReal[10, {500, 3}];)
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This works also for e.g. `data = Transpose[{RandomReal[10, {500}], RandomReal[5, {500}], 
   RandomReal[2, {500}]}]`.